# Angular error when loading project on Mac

Tags: macos, angular, angular-cli

We are developing an app using node for the server/api and angular for the frontend, and currently we am facing a strange problem on one of my team members machine.

We are 3 developers 2 of us use Windows 10 and the other uses MacOS 10.12.5, which is the one that presents the following problem when trying to load the client on a browser:

```
zone.js:642 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: MdButton,MdButton ("<span>[ERROR ->]<button class="butron" md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{menuItem}}</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMe"): ng:///AppModule/MenuComponentComponent.html@0:6
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: MdMenuItem,MdMenuItem ("}}</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <a [routerLink]="['/participant']" routerLinkActive="active">[ERROR ->]<button md-menu-item>Participante</button></a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/company']" routerLinkActive="act"): ng:///AppModule/MenuComponentComponent.html@2:63
More than one component matched on this element.
[...and so on]
```

The development environment is as follows:

- Node 7.9.0
- npm 4.2.0

and the package.json of the front end is:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@covalent/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3-2",
    "@covalent/dynamic-forms": "^1.0.0-beta.3-2",
    "@covalent/highlight": "^1.0.0-beta.3-2",
    "@covalent/http": "^1.0.0-beta.3-2",
    "@covalent/markdown": "^1.0.0-beta.3-2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-uploader": "^2.2.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

We have verified that we all 3 are on the same versions of node, npm, all the same packages and we are at the same commit on the same branch, but whenever we do ng serve on the Mac computer everything loads correctly on the node console but the above error appears when trying to load the app, but on the Windows environments we are unable to reproduce the issue as everything works fine and as expected.

We have deleted and cloned the project and done npm install several times, deleted just the node_modules folder and reinstalled them, reinstalled node and npm, called the ng from the global package or the local one, and so on, none has worked so far.

I have done some searches and it seems it appeared to some people on earlier versions of angular 2 but most of them were fixed by updating packages, and as we 3 have the same we don't think that is the problem, has anyone else faced something similar? We are pretty much clueless at this point.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Edit: I have to add that this started happening since I updated the project from the angular-cli beta to the stable release and angular from 2.3.1 to 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

Clearing it all and cloning the project again then deleting all the '^' from the package.json everything worked as expected. It was probably an updated package from something that was making the conflict.